# How to get rid off last column right double border?

Tags: tabulator

Is there a way to make the right border of the last column to be at the position of the outer border? In other words, how to get rid off that nasty fakey column to the right of the last column?

[image]

Here is the Tabulator object:

```
new Tabulator("#campaignsInfo", {
    layout: "fitColumns",
    reactiveData: true,
    data: campaignsInfo,
    columns: [
        { title: "id", field: "id", visible: false},
        { title: "Completed", field: "completed", width: "90"
            , align: "center", formatter: "tickCross", headerSort: false},
        { title: "Started", field: "surveyStarted", width: "70"
            , align: "center", formatter: "tickCross", headerSort: false},
        { title: "Invite Sent", field: "emailSent", width: "90"
            , align: "center", formatter: "tickCross", headerSort: false},
        { title: "Client ID", field: "policyID", width: "15%", headerSort: false},
        { title: "Completion Date", field: "surveyResponseCompletedTimestamp", width: "30%"
            , formatter: "textarea", headerSort: false},
        { title: "Status", field: "locked", align: "center", headerSort: false
            , formatter: printLock, cellClick: unlock
            , tooltip: lockTooltip
        },
    ],
});
```

Here is an updated image of the last column, after a suggestion of Jose P. has been applied. As you can see the cell right border is still is in place, which is not quite what we want. I believe it's something to do with the tabulator, as when I increase the width of the browser window the border getting wider, as the column width is recalculated and re-applied. Also I see an error in the console `ResizeObserver loop completed with undelivered notifications.`

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to .css file:

```
.tabulator-row .tabulator-cell[tabulator-field="locked"]{
  border-right: 0px;
}
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col[tabulator-field="locked"]{
  border-right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you for the idea, though it's not completely fixing the issue, but it's a step in the right direction. Still there is one artifact visible. Do you think it's possible to fix? Please see my update for the question. Thank you!

Comment: Maybe try with: border-right: 1px transparent;
But I'm just guessing